# PageBreak in flow documents at runtime

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

I AM able to get a text file on a flow document but now I have to divide the contents in proper pagebreaks at runtime i.e if contents are huge they shud get itself in number of pages that too at runtime.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TextOnFlowDoc
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Page1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Page1 : Page
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

            paragraph.Inlines.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Lis.txt"));
            paragraph.FontFamily = new FontFamily("CourierNew");

            FlowDocument document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);
            // FlowDocumentReader rdr = new FlowDocumentReader();
            FlowDocScl.Document = document;
        }
    }
}
```

Now this "FlowDocScl" is now a flow document and needs to be breaked into pages AT RUNTIME.

Comment: Please read the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and look at the preview before posting butchered code.

Comment: Sorry, I'll take care of format from my next post onwards but right now im in gr8 need of ur help....please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Now Iam intending to annotate a flow document content in a manner that only the alternate line of text (like 1st,3rd,5th...) gets colored while the other ones remain as it is. Please provide any help in this regard.....

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you want custom page-breaks, if you display it in a [`FlowDocumentPageViewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentpageviewer.aspx) for example you get automatic breaks if the content is too large for the viewer.

If you must insert breaks on demand you need to split the document in [`Blocks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.block.aspx), those have a property called [`BreakPageBefore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.block.breakpagebefore.aspx) which when set to true inserts a page break before that block obviously.

Something like this (untested):

```
private void BreakAndAddText(string text)
{
    var pages = text.Split(new string[] { "\\f" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    foreach (var page in pages)
    {
        document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(page)) { BreakPageBefore = true });
    }
}
```

Comment: One more help H.B. , can i extract each line of the data being displayed using above code at runtime ?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean by that; if you have refence to the docunment you pretty much can do anything at runtime, you just need to step into the hierarchy and find the elements which contain the text, normally those are `Runs`.

Comment: Can you kindly provide a way like a code sample in which any properties of the reader/viewer are used....Actually I want to span through every line of text being displayed on reader/viewer, because i have to induce line break after a special character '\f' which is included in the text. This can only be done if i create a check for every line of data, the moment i will encounter '\f' i will use BreakPageBefore  property.

Comment: I added some code which might work; in your original code you add all the text to one paragraph, i suggest you call a method similar to the one i wrote instead, then you do not need to extract the text from the paragraph.