# Escape Sequence for Print to new page

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

I am trying to print a very long string using a Flow document.

I am generating a string like this:

```
foreach (item listitem in mylist)
{
    string aa += listitem.firststring + " " + listitem.secondstring + "\n";
    string aa += "---------------------------\n";
}
```

I am getting each value printed to a new line because of the `\n`, but I need each list item to print to a new page.

What escape sequence do I need at the end of "`string aa+="---------------------------\n";"` to achieve this?

This is the code I am using for Print

```
if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
   // Create a FlowDocument dynamically. 
   FlowDocument doc = CreateFlowDocument(aa );
   doc.Name = "FlowDoc";
   doc.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
   doc.PageHeight = printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight;
   doc.PageWidth = printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth;
   doc.PagePadding = new Thickness(25);
   IDocumentPaginatorSource idpSource = doc;
   printDialog.PrintDocument(idpSource.DocumentPaginator, "Printing");
}
```

Comment: As a side note, consider using a StringBuilder to append your string rather than concatenating like that in a loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PageBreak in flow documents at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962472/pagebreak-in-flow-documents-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [Page break](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break) `\f`

```
string aa += "---------------------------\f";
```

Comment: I also tried with "\f" and "\\f" but.I am not getting the next items to the next page.